# Mat select - Get old value of selectionChange

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a project in which I have a form containing a `mat-select` selector. Whenever the user changes the input, I show the user a dialog to confirm this operation. Now:

The `selectionChange()` notifies when the value was changed and passes the new value as `$event`.

**Is there a way to get the old value to return back in case when the user canceled the dialog?**

I don't want to do the dirty way like, saving the current value in a seperate member variable.

Template:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTextCountingType" 
            (selectionChange)="select($event)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of countingTypeOptions" 
              [value]="option.value">
    {{option.text | translate}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

TS:

```
select(option: MatSelectChange): void { 
    this.openConfirmDeletionDialog().pipe(
        filter((respose) => {
            // HERE IS WHERE I NEED IT.
            if(Boolean(reponse) === false) {
                this.selectedTextCountingType = oldValue;
            }
            return Boolean(reponse); 
        })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a workaround for you expected behavior, since you are binding a model to that mat select when the event `selectionChange` is triggered your element is already updated , but if you print out the model it will be the literal that was formed when the select-tag was last updated by angular, in your case since you a ngFor of a list of types you can later find it by text, value or any other property you may prefer.

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTextCountingType" 
            (selectionChange)="select($event, '{{selectedTextCountingType.value}}')">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of countingTypeOptions" 
              [value]="option.value">
    {{option.text | translate}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

and in your component you should have the value as a string

```
select(option: MatSelectChange, oldValue: string): void { 
    this.openConfirmDeletionDialog().pipe(
        filter((respose) => {
            if(Boolean(reponse) === false) {
                this.selectedTextCountingType = this.selectedTextCountingType.find(countingType => countingType.value === oldValue);
            }
            return Boolean(reponse); 
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: But if you ngModel only save a number or string, this doesn't works, you must use openedChange to save a temporal previus value and when selectionChange jumps, you have a prev value saved.