# Old value of the event in ngModelChange when ngModel has the default value set

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to get the ngModelChange old value. I want to detect if the dropdown value has changed inside the component to call the function repeatedly.

HTML:

```
        <select id = "translation" (ngModelChange)="getTranslationOnChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedDevice" class="form-control float-right col-md-3">
            <option [ngValue]="language.id" *ngFor="let language of languages">{{language.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

the value of `selectedDevice` is set to `"en"` by default as I want to set "en" as default in the dropdown.
How do I get the old value of the dropdown as well the new value?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible.

I had a similar problem here: [Mat select - Get old value of selectionChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522591/mat-select-get-old-value-of-selectionchange)

Another workaround using `Subject`: [How to obtain previous and new value from Angular mat-select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513082/how-to-obtain-previous-and-new-value-from-angular-mat-select)

> You can handle previous and current value by pushing the value into a Subject, and observe this Subject using the pairwise operator. This operator will emit the previous and the current value of the stream.
>    (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html)

Example:

```js
export class YOU_COMPONENT{

  private data: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  checkTitle(value){
    this.data.next(value);
  }

  observeDataChange():Observable<[]>{
     // this return an observable of an array that contains [previous, current] data
     return this.data.asObservable().pipe(pairwise());
  }

}
```

In the end I took the workaround by having a value with the prefix `old` in its name to have it. There is another workaround that you find in my linked question.

I hope that it at least give you some inspirations. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I asked some of my collegues as well, but it seems like we have to deal with it for now.

Comment: ok, I can't add the old prefix as I have a use case where I require the old value to detect the change.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do some workaround to get the value in the getTranslationOnChange(). Not sure but may be this can serve the purpose.

HTML:-

```
<select id = "translation" (click) = "getVal(selectedDevice)" (ngModelChange)="getTranslationOnChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedDevice" class="form-control float-right col-md-3">
            <option [ngValue]="language" *ngFor="let language of languages">{{language.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

TS:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'src/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
public languages = [{'id':1,'name':'en'},{'id':2,'name':'pt'},{'id':3,'name':'es'}];
public counter = 0;
public oldval;
public selectedDevice;
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedDevice = this.languages[0];
}
getTranslationOnChange($event){
  console.log("new Value=",$event," +old value= ",this.oldval);
  this.counter++;
}
getVal(event){
  if(!this.counter) {
    this.oldval = event.name;
  }
  this.counter = 0;
}
}
```

I hope it helps. Thanks